# Vue+element popover can not change current-page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, element

when I hide the `popover` and open it up again, the value of `currentPage` hasn't been changed.

HTML CODE:

```
<el-popover
  placement="bottom"
  trigger="click"
  title="网段详情"
  @hide="popoverHide">
    <el-table :data="inner_table_data.slice((insidePage-1)*5,insidePage*5)" stripe height="100%">
      <el-table-column></el-table-column>                             
    </el-table>
    <el-pagination
      @current-change="insideChange"
      :page-size="5"                     
      layout="prev, pager, next"
      :total="30">
    </el-pagination>
    <a href="javascript:;" slot="reference">
      <span v-html="scope.row.subnet"></span>
    </a>
</el-popover>
```

JS CODE:

```
popoverHide: function () {
  this.insidePage = 1;
  this.inner_table_data = '';
}
```

demo link is here: https://jsfiddle.net/npfL4e7h/10/

Change page number in pagination, hide it and open it up again, the data is the first page's data while page number is the number before hiding the popover. Adding a :current-page doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Can you provide me a link to the Popover element? I cannot seem to find it on Element UI website.

Comment: demo link is here https://jsfiddle.net/npfL4e7h/10/   , change page number in pagination, hide it and open it up again, the data is the first page's data while page number is the number before hide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `current-page` property to the pagination.

```
<el-pagination
  @current-change="insideChange"
  :page-size="5"                     
  layout="prev, pager, next"
  :total="30"
  :current-page="insidePage"
>
```